# How to simulate a mouse pointer?

Tags: java, android, mouse-cursor

Is there a way in Android to simulate a mouse pointer, what I mean by that is : I want to display a mouse pointer on my app, and move it to certain locations by giving it [x,y] so user can see where the mouse is pointing to ?

In Java Swing, I could use a robot and it can do "mouseMove(int x, int y)", nothing similar in Android ?

Comment: Nothing built in.  Its always possible to do on your own though- create a view overlay for your main window, and draw a cursor yourself in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an animation set, you will want to get your screen coordinates another way this was a hack solution for a college class

```
private AnimationSet fullAnimation;

// some onCreate for a view
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// setting the AnimationSet
fullAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);

Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
int moveSize1 = (int) (width / 2.80);
int moveSize2 = (int) (height / 3.7);
int moveSize3 = (int) (width / 3.3);
int moveSize4 = -1*(int) (height / 1.7);
int moveSize5 = (int) (width / 2.85);

move1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, moveSize1, 0,0);
move1.setDuration(5000);
move1.setFillAfter(true);
fullAnimation.addAnimation(move1);

move2 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,moveSize2);
move2.setDuration(5000);
move2.setFillAfter(true);
move2.setStartOffset(6000);
fullAnimation.addAnimation(move2);
```

Comment: https://github.com/jinxTelesis/AndroidGameV2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/calcounter/com/individualproject3/EasyLevel1.java